# python - string conversion array and comma delimited

Tags: python, regex, string, format

I have data in python that needs to convert string from

```
string = "[-8.27104300e-02  9.09485668e-02  7.72242993e-02]"
```

to this

```
converted_string = "-8.27104300e-02, 9.09485668e-02, 7.72242993e-02"
```

Basically removing brackets [] and putting in comma for the spaces

How do I achieve this ?

Comment: This doesn't require regex at all. This is a simple string slicing operation to remove the brackets, and then a `str.replace` call to replace 2 spaces with a comma and a space.

Comment: @Rawing It may or may not, depending on whether the space width is fixed or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need regex for removing the braces. That's just a simple slicing operation. However, I *could* see the need for it when substituting whitespace, especially when you have varying width whitespace separators.

```
>>> import re
>>> re.sub('\s+', ', ', string[1:-1])
```

```
'-8.27104300e-02, 9.09485668e-02, 7.72242993e-02'
```

However, if you can guarantee a fixed separator width of 2 spaces, then `str.replace` works well here -

```
>>> string[1:-1].replace('  ', ', ')
'-8.27104300e-02, 9.09485668e-02, 7.72242993e-02'
```